# Guzzle Post multipart/form-data Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, multipartform-data, guzzle

I have problem about post using guzzle with multipart/form-data. i using laravel 8 and guzzle version ^7.3.

this is my code
[image: this is my code]

but i get this result
[image: but i get this result]

Help me, please
Thanks

Comment: change content to contents in each item

Comment: add your code in question not as a photo read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/9471283)

Comment: Try pasting your code instead of uploading images. That way it will be easier for users to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Each entry of the multi-part form should have a `contents` property. You have to change `content` to `contents`.

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'field_name',
            'contents' => 'abc'
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'other_file',
            'contents' => 'hello',
            'filename' => 'filename.txt',
            'headers'  => [
                'X-Foo' => 'this is an extra header to include'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Checkout the docs: [Guzzle Post Form Requests](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#post-form-requests)